# My resolution is wider than my monitor and I can't figure out how to fix it

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution

I have Ubuntu 17.10 installed natively on my PC. My video adapter is a Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060, with a 55" 4k Samsung panel connected to it.

The top and bottom are right, but the left and right sides of the desktop overhang the sides of the display by about 128 pixels on each side; meaning I can't see the icons down the left side, or interact with the little widget tray in the top-right.

In the "Displays" applet, the monitor is showing a resolution of

```
4096 x 2160 (9:5)
```

which is weird. I don't know where that is coming from.

There is a resolution available of "3840 x 2160 (16:9)" which is correct, but when I attempt to select it, the screen goes black and loses sync until the changes time out.

I have used xrandr and cvt to add a new mode, but it still doesn't work.

For now I modified my television to force fit the display into its boundaries, but that's not a "fix", rather just a workaround for now.

Does anybody know how I can get rid of the rogue 4096 x 2160 resolution and get the proper 3840 x 2160 resolution to work??

Thanks in advance!